# Python range issue

Tags: python, while-loop, range

I am writing a program in which it needs to determine the range of the number as if I put 15 in user_input 'a' so it should print range from 'a' to 'b' but unfortunately i'm unable to work it out can anyone please help me with this. This is my code:

```
a = int(raw_input("How many did you say you're going to count down? "))
b = int(raw_input("When are you actually going to stop? "))
i = 0
for i in range(a, b):
    i = i + 1
    print i
```

and I want it to work like this:

```
How many did you say you're going to count down? 15
When are you actually going to stop? 8
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
```

OR

```
How many did you say you're going to count down? 6
When are you actually going to stop? 4
6
5
4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop can be:

```
a = int(raw_input("How many did you say you're going to count down? "))
b = int(raw_input("When are you actually going to stop? "))

for i in range(a, b-1, -1):
    print i
```

(assuming the count decreases).

What you must know is:

1. The `for` loop does the decrement for you (no need for `i = i-1` like in C).
2. `range(a, b-1, -1)` is a list (in Python 2) that goes from `a` to `b-1` (not included), by steps of `-1`. You can try to do, in a Python shell, `print range(10, 5, -1)`, for instance. You can also check the output of `range(5, 11, 2)`, to understand better what `range()` does.

Comment: @rocker789: Now it does. Your loop was counting upwards (twice).